# Rails dynamic default_url_options setting for devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

The logic for url_options is set within a Rails 7 application logic as a dynamic value, thus the configuration setting is disabled  `# config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'some_domain' }`

routes are amended to allow altering of the passwords controller:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { passwords: 'users/passwords' }
```

And the controller action is amended to define the default_url.  The new action *also* injects a host parameter.  Upon checking

```
   def create
 Rails.logger.info params[:user][:host]
 Rails.logger.info request.host
     default_url_options = { host: request.host }
     super
   end
```

the logs indicate for both logger items `localhost`.  Yet the action does not complete as a couple of issues are encountered:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Initializing Mail::Sendmail with :arguments of type String is deprecated.  
Instead ensure :arguments is an array of strings, e.g. ["-i", "-t"]  
(called from create at /Users/deploy/r/some/app/controllers/users/passwords_controller.rb:16)
[...]
ActionView::Template::Error (Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter,  
set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true):
```

Why is the action not handling the given parameters or request info?
What is mistaken in the above approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unexpectedly, after having toiled with different avenues, the following ended up working:

```
class Users::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController

   def create
     Rails.logger.info request.host  #  just checking ;-)
     #     default_url_options = { host: request.host }  # no go
     #     default_url_options[:host] = request.host   # no go
     Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = request.host
     super
   end
```

This however implies that every mailer's create action establish the default_url_options before launching.